# How to automatically update a monthly date and bi-weekly google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

How would I be able to have a cell automatically update the date once the current date has passed?

For example, the date 30/3/2023 will automatically update to 30/4/2023. I would like to be able to do this for monthly dates & bi-weekly dates.

Comment: You need `AppScript` coding.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what exact dates you're looking for, but you can have cells always reflect the current date or a reference to it using the [today function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en). You can then leverage that to get a variety of values.

One key component is to turn calculations to be hourly in the spreadsheet settings (under file). This will ensure that if you open and even don't change anything, it will be up to date with current dates.

[image]

[Here's a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18kl2gv3s62lTi25WLO9mk_RsdK-kG0tDXPO9UdOHcF0/edit?usp=sharing) with a variety of functions.

[image]